# For how long will the UK government / parliament elected on December 12, 2019 remain (not counting other possible non-regular elections)?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, parliament

For how long will the UK government / parliament elected on December 12, 2019 remain (serve?), if we're not counting any possible new non-regular elections?

Put in another way: When will the next regular general election for UK parliament be held?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The current law — the [2011 Fixed Term Parliaments Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/14/enacted) — sets the next election as “the first Thursday in May of the fifth year after the last General Election”, which would make the next scheduled General Election the ***2nd of May 2024***.

Comment: Also not counting any potential acts that might amend or repeal the FTPA.

Comment: @Jan you can only really go by current law, as otherwise the question is essentially unanswerable...

Comment: Correct, was intended more as a hint towards OP since they explicitly noted non-regular elections but not any changes to the FTPA.

Comment: Note that the Tories explicitly promised to repeal the FTPA in their manifesto, and given they never wanted it and suffered under it it's reasonable to assume that they will do so. This does not materially change the answer though IMO, as the previous rules mandated a 5 year term at maximum and given their strong majority now there's no reason to suspect they'll call an earlier election.

Comment: @Moo FTPA *will* be repealed so this answer is wrong. It's not unanswerable, the answer is "undetermined".

Comment: [This Research Briefing](https://researchbriefings.parliament.uk/ResearchBriefing/Summary/SN05085) from the House of Commons library provides confirmation of 2nd May 2024.

Comment: @TripeHound It only confirms 2nd May 2024 under the assumption that the FTPA remains in force.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Which is all one can do until such time it ceases to be in force. The answer also (implicitly) assumes there won't be WW3 in the interim, and that an asteroid will not devastate life on earth in 2022. There are many things that _could_ happen to change the date... repealing FTPA is only one of them.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica That's not true - the 2010-2015 parliament that introduced the act ran to the date mandated in the act, with the general election held on 7 May 2015. Part of the reason for the act was presumably to increase the stability of the Conservative - Liberal Democrat coalition, and prevent either party from forcing an early election

Comment: @PhillS I was going by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-term_Parliaments_Act_2011 "To date, no elections have been held upon the expiry of a fixed term set by the Act."

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica Not unreasonable - the same page also has the line "The 2015 general election was held on 7 May 2015, the first, and so far only, use of the Act to dictate the date of the election." The line you quote might be a mistake, or a bit of text left over from when the article was first written, before 2015. (Actually I just checked the edit history - the line exists as you quoted it in a randomly selected version of the page from 2014, so I think it's just never been removed after it became out of date).

Comment: @PhillS and that's why you should always specify "as of" in Wikipedia articles.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica That it ran to term is also confirmed in the Research Briefing I mentioned earlier: "_The Fixed-term Parliaments Act 2011 set the date of first general election, after it received Royal Assent, as 7 May 2015. Accordingly the 2010 Parliament was dissolved on 30 March 2015._", whereas its description of subsequent elections include "_was scheduled to take place_".

Comment: @TripeHound \*sigh\* The possibility of Word War 3, a cataclysmic asteroid, a zombie plague or any other fantasy you might mention are not remotely comparable to the repeal of the FTPA, which is (a) of direct and extreme relevance to the question and (b) something that the government has promised to do and has the power to do. Honestly, you're being utterly ridiculous.

Comment: @DanScally A five-year maximum term would allow the next election to be fully six months later than this answer states. And it's pretty common for parties with a large majority to call an election after about four years, assuming they feel they're still popular enough to win. Better to cement another term than extend the current one to its maximum and risk something happening. For example, Blair called two elections after four years each and won them; Brown knew he was likely to lose so went as long as possible.

Answer (score 8):

The previous answer was correct at the time it was written.

However, the Fixed-term Parliaments Act 2011 was repealed by the [Dissolution and Calling of Parliament Act 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolution_and_Calling_of_Parliament_Act_2022), which returned the (effective) power to call an election to the Prime Minister.

Quoting the linked Wikipedia page:

> Section 4 of the Act provided: "If it has not been dissolved earlier, a Parliament dissolves at the beginning of the day that is the fifth anniversary of the day on which it first met." For the MPs elected in the 2019 United Kingdom general election, who first met on 17 December 2019, this means the fifth-anniversary date of 17 December 2024 and the latest possible polling day 25 working days later, which is **24 January 2025**.

The 25 working days comes from the timetable laid out in [Part 1 of Schedule 1 of the Representation of the People Act 1983](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1983/2/schedule/1/part/I), as amended.

Comment: It's likely, though not certain, that if the current parliament continues close to the end of its term, then an election would be held a little early, to avoid campaigning during the Christmas/New Year holiday season. That's a much more important holiday season in the UK than the US: much of the UK shuts down between Christmas and New Year., and campaigning would be regarded as annoying, probably reducing turn-out.

Comment: @JohnDallman Indeed. Prior to the FTPA, PMs had tended to call elections in the spring anyway; prior to 2019, the last elections not to be in April, May or June were the two in 1974 (Feb and Oct that year); before that, there's less of a trend, with a number of autumn elections.